# Change FAB background color with MotionLayout and MotionScene

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have a FloatingActionButton that I want to transition to another color with the use of MotionLayout and MotionScene.

This is my FAB in my layout file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/map_activity_scene"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/lightPurple"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_layers_24px"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

And this is my MotionScene

```
<MotionScene xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Transition
            app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
            app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
            app:duration="400">

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/lightPurple"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_layers_24px"
                    app:tint="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="backgroundTint"
                app:customColorValue="@color/lightPurple" />
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/map_fab_transform"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/revealLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/revealLayout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/revealLayout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/revealLayout">

            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="backgroundTint"
                app:customColorValue="@color/map_fab_transform" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

When I run the scene the fab moves to its correct place but the color does not change nor does the icon get removed from it. It seems that any of the `app` properties do not get applied.

How do I change to color of the fab and remove the icon in the fab with MotionLayout?

Comment: I checked your code and tried a lot but after checking FloatingActionButton inner class I found there is not setter and getter for backgroundTint and therefore we are not able to change it in motionlayout. Also, you can change icon color "colorFilter" in motion layout.

Comment: I tried colorFilter and that only changes the color of the icon. I guess I will go another route, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 app:backgroundTint="@color/lightPurple"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_layers_24px"
 app:tint="@color/white"
```

Constraint does not take any of these tags.
It only takes a limited set of tags
You will have to set those with custom attributes. 
If you want MotionLayout to interpolate the custom attributes you must set them on start and end ConstraintSet.

Comment: Setting the color on start and end did not change the color, you can see I have the colors set in my example already. The tint colors dont work in MotionScene